# Counter system using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, datetime

When i add events in my database i have field for starting and ending date. So if i store event in my database with starting date in 8h and 25min, output in event page will be 116 days 7 hours 33 minutes. Problem is why i got that 116 days?? My code is this:

Javascript code for counter:

```
if ($(".counter-widget").length > 0) {
    var countCurrent = $(".counter-widget").attr("data-countDate");
    $(".countdown").downCount({
        date: countCurrent ,
        offset: 0
    });
}
```

Event page:

```
<div class="box-widget counter-widget gradient-bg" data-countDate="06/02/2020">
    <div class="countdown fl-wrap">
        <div class="countdown-item">
            <span class="days rot">00</span>
            <p>days</p>
        </div>
        <div class="countdown-item">
            <span class="hours rot">08</span>
            <p>hours</p>
        </div>
        <div class="countdown-item no-dec">
            <span class="minutes rot2">25</span>
            <p>minutes </p>
        </div>
        <div class="countdown-item-seconds">
            <span class="seconds rot2">00</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Another Javascript code for countdown is this:

```
(function($){$.fn.downCount=function(options,callback){var settings=$.extend({date:null,offset:null},options);if(!settings.date){$.error('Date is not defined.')}if(!Date.parse(settings.date)){$.error('Incorrect date format, it should look like this, 12/24/2012 12:00:00.')}var container=this;var currentDate=function(){var date=new Date();var utc=date.getTime()+(date.getTimezoneOffset()*60000);var new_date=new Date(utc+(3600000*settings.offset));return new_date};function countdown(){var target_date=new Date(settings.date),current_date=currentDate();var difference=target_date-current_date;if(difference<0){clearInterval(interval);if(callback&&typeof callback==='function')callback();return}var _second=1000,_minute=_second*60,_hour=_minute*60,_day=_hour*24;var days=Math.floor(difference/_day),hours=Math.floor((difference%_day)/_hour),minutes=Math.floor((difference%_hour)/_minute),seconds=Math.floor((difference%_minute)/_second);days=(String(days).length>=2)?days:'0'+days;hours=(String(hours).length>=2)?hours:'0'+hours;minutes=(String(minutes).length>=2)?minutes:'0'+minutes;seconds=(String(seconds).length>=2)?seconds:'0'+seconds;var ref_days=(days===1)?'day':'days',ref_hours=(hours===1)?'hour':'hours',ref_minutes=(minutes===1)?'minute':'minutes',ref_seconds=(seconds===1)?'second':'seconds';container.find('.days').text(days);container.find('.hours').text(hours);container.find('.minutes').text(minutes);container.find('.seconds').text(seconds);container.find('.days_ref').text(ref_days);container.find('.hours_ref').text(ref_hours);container.find('.minutes_ref').text(ref_minutes);container.find('.seconds_ref').text(ref_seconds)};var interval=setInterval(countdown,1000)}})(jQuery);
```

Output on Event page will be with this code: **116 days 7 hours 33 minutes 13 sec**. How? Where im wrong? Should i need to add timezone to my code or what?

Thanks for all

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207392/discussion-on-question-by-complycode-counter-system-using-php).

Answer (score 0):

Problem was solved using PHP Script:

Solved code:

```
<?php
    $rem = strtotime($result->EventStartEnd) - time();
    $day = floor($rem / 86400);
    $hr  = floor(($rem % 86400) / 3600);
    $min = floor(($rem % 3600) / 60);
    $sec = ($rem % 60);
    if($day) echo "$day Days ";
    if($hr) echo "$hr Hours ";
    if($min) echo "$min Minutes ";
    if($sec) echo "$sec Seconds ";
    echo "Remaining...";
?>
```